# How to Insert combining two different selects in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, stored-procedures, insert

I want to insert into a table as part of a longer procedure using SQL Server 2008. The table for the insert has two columns, itemID and tag.

The tag part is selected from an input parameter (xml) and works as intended with the line below. My problem is that the `itemID` needs to be selected from a temp table (`@temp`) at the same time. How can I achieve this here ?

**My SQL (only relevant part):**

```
INSERT  INTO RC_Items_Tags
(
        itemID,
        tag
)
SELECT 
        itemID,
        ParamValues.tag.value('.', 'varchar(255)')
FROM 
        @xmlTags.nodes('/tags/tag') AS ParamValues(tag)
```

Comment: So, every `itemID` from every row in `@temp` should be given the same tag value?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, could you give some example data (both input and output)?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Yes, the would all get the same itemID.

Comment: @DavidG: This is only about how to get the itemID from the temp table (@temp), everything else works already as intended. To complete the insert each of the tags needs to get the same itemID assigned that is in the temp table (there is only one column itemID).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just perform a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
INSERT  INTO RC_Items_Tags
(
        itemID,
        tag
)
SELECT 
        t.itemID,
        ParamValues.tag.value('.', 'varchar(255)')
FROM 
        @xmlTags.nodes('/tags/tag') AS ParamValues(tag)
              CROSS JOIN
        @temp t
```

Comment: Perfect - that's exactly what I was looking for. Sorry, I am still pretty new to SQL. Will accept as soon as I can.